# Read in a file and Create a double linked list in c

Tags: c, doubly-linked-list

So I'm new to C coding and I'm having trouble with creating a linked list with the following code. The problem I've been having is that the fscanf changes the variables every time when it reads in something. So my head pointer value keeps getting changed. Is there a way to fix this? Thank you!

**After a few discussion, I've realized it's because the mnemonic in the struct is a pointer, so the mnemonic of head is going to change since it's just pointing at the pointer. Is there a way to fix this problem without changing the struct itself? (meaning leaving the mnemonic in struct Instr as a pointer)**

```
void linkTypeInstr(struct InstrType *it, char *c, FILE *mfp){
    int count = 0;
    char type[2], mnemonic[11];
    uint32_t uid = 0, pretty = 0;
    struct Instr *head = NULL;
    struct Instr *ptr = NULL;
    /*read through the file in format*/
    while(fscanf(mfp, "%s %u %s %u ", type, &uid, mnemonic, &pretty) != NULL){
        if(head != NULL)
            printf("head: %s\n", head -> mnemonic);
        /*check if is the match type*/
        if(*type == *c){
            /*make a new struct instr for the item want to add*/
            struct Instr *temp = malloc(sizeof(struct Instr));
            memset(temp, 0, sizeof(struct Instr));
            temp -> uid = uid;
            temp -> pretty = pretty;
            temp -> mnemonic = mnemonic;
            temp -> next = NULL;
            temp -> prev = NULL;
            printf("temp: %s\n", temp -> mnemonic);
            printf("count: %d\n", count);
            /*check if list is empty, set ptr to head*/
            if(count == 0){
                head = temp;
                count++;
            }
            /*if list is not empty, find the place to put the item in alphabetical order*/
            else{
                ptr = head;
                printf("head: %s\n", head -> mnemonic);
                while(ptr != NULL){
                    /*if temp should come after ptr in the order*/
                    if(strcmp(ptr -> mnemonic, temp -> mnemonic) < 0){
                        if(ptr -> next == NULL){
                            ptr -> next = temp;
                            temp -> prev = ptr;
                            count++;
                            ptr = NULL;
                        }
                        else if(strcmp(temp -> mnemonic, ptr -> next -> mnemonic) < 0){
                            temp -> next = ptr -> next; 
                            ptr -> next -> prev = temp;
                            ptr -> next = temp;
                            temp -> prev = ptr;
                            count++;
                            ptr = NULL;
                        }
                        else 
                            /*if should be after ptr -> next*/
                            ptr = ptr -> next;
                    }
                    /*if temp should come before ptr in the order*/
                    else if(strcmp(temp -> mnemonic, ptr -> mnemonic) < 0){
                        if(ptr -> prev == NULL){
                            ptr -> prev = temp;
                            temp -> next = ptr;
                            head = temp;
                            count++;
                            ptr = NULL;
                        }
                        else if(strcmp(ptr -> prev -> mnemonic, temp -> mnemonic) < 0){
                            ptr -> prev -> next = temp;
                            temp -> prev = ptr -> prev;
                            ptr -> prev = temp;
                            temp -> next = ptr;
                            count++;
                            ptr = NULL;
                        }
                        else
                            /*if should be before ptr -> prev*/
                            ptr = ptr -> prev;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    it -> count = count;
    it -> head = head;
}


struct Instr {
        uint32_t uid; /* Unique identification bits */
        uint32_t pretty; /* The type of pretty print format this Instr is */
        char *mnemonic; /* The human readable mnemonic */
        struct Instr *next; /* Pointer for doubly linked list */
        struct Instr *prev; /* Pointer for doubly linked list */
};

struct InstrType {
        char type; /* Should be R, I, or J */
        size_t count; /* Length of Instr list */
        struct InstrType *next; /* Points to the next InstrType node */
        struct InstrType *prev; /* Points to the next InstrType node */
        struct Instr *head; /* Points to the first Instr node of this type */
};
```

The file im trying to read look something like this:

```
r 00000020 add 3
r 00000021 addu 3
r 00000022 sub 3
r 00000023 subu 3
r 00000018 mult 2
r 00000019 multu 2
r 0000001a div 1
r 0000001b divu 1
r 00000010 mfhi 0
r 00000011 mthi 0
r 00000012 mflo 0
r 00000013 mtlo 0
r 00000000 sll 8
r 00000002 srl 8
r 00000003 sra 8
r 00000004 sllv 3
r 00000006 srlv 3
r 00000007 srav 3
r 00000024 and 3
r 00000025 or 3
r 00000026 xor 3
r 00000027 nor 3
r 0000002a slt 3
r 0000002b sltu 3
r 00000008 jr 0
r 00000009 jalr 2
r 0000000c syscall 5
i 20000000 addi 2
i 24000000 addiu 2
i 3c000000 lui 2
i 28000000 slti 2
i 2c000000 sltiu 2
i 30000000 andi 2
i 34000000 ori 2
i 38000000 xori 2
i 80000000 lb 4
i 84000000 lh 4
i 88000000 lwl 4
i 8c000000 lw 4
i 90000000 lbu 4
i 98000000 lwr 4
i a0000000 sb 4
i a4000000 sh 4
i a8000000 swl 4
```

and the result when i run this always end up changing my head ptr to the new temp created:

```
temp: add
count: 0
head: addu
temp: addu
count: 1
head: addu
...
```

code calling the function looks like this:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    int c;
    int iFlag = 0, oFlag = 0;
    char mFileName[256] = "instruction_mapping.txt";
    char oFileName[256];
    char iFileName[256];
    extern char *optarg;
    FILE *mfp, *ifp, *ofp;

    /*create three struct instrtype nodes*/
    struct InstrType *itR = malloc(sizeof(struct InstrType));
    struct InstrType *itI = malloc(sizeof(struct InstrType));
    struct InstrType *itJ = malloc(sizeof(struct InstrType));

    memset(itR, 0, sizeof(struct InstrType));
    memset(itI, 0, sizeof(struct InstrType));
    memset(itJ, 0, sizeof(struct InstrType));

    /*link the struct instrtype together*/
    if(itR != NULL && itI != NULL && itJ != NULL){
        itR -> prev = NULL;
        itR -> next = itI;
        itI -> prev = itR;
        itI -> next = itJ;
        itJ -> prev = itI;
        itJ -> next = NULL;
    }

    /*set up instrtypes*/
    itR -> type = 'R';
    itI -> type = 'I';
    itJ -> type = 'J';

    /* parse arguments */
    while ((c = getopt(argc, argv, "m:i:o:h")) != -1){
        switch(c){
            case 'h':
                USAGE(argv[0]);
                return EXIT_SUCCESS;
            case 'm':
                strcpy(mFileName, optarg);
                break;
            case 'i':
                iFlag = 1;
                strcpy(iFileName, optarg);
                break;
            case 'o':
                oFlag = 1;
                strcpy(oFileName, optarg);
                break;
            default:
                USAGE(argv[0]);
                return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
    }

    /*check -i and -o must be in argv*/
    if(iFlag == 1 && oFlag == 1){
        mfp = fopen(mFileName, "r");
        if(mfp == NULL){
            printf("Cannot open instruction mapping file\n");
            EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
        printf("mapping file: %s\n", mFileName);
        ifp = fopen(iFileName, "r");
        if(ifp == NULL){
            printf("Cannot open input file\n");
            EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
        printf("input file: %s\n", iFileName);
        ofp = fopen(oFileName, "w");
        if(ofp == NULL){
            printf("Error creating or writing file\n");
            EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
        printf("output file: %s\n", oFileName);

        /* make linked lists of instr in R, I, J instrtype */
        linkTypeInstr(itR, "r", mfp);
        linkTypeInstr(itI, "i", mfp);
        linkTypeInstr(itJ, "j", mfp);


        if(mfp != NULL)
            fclose(mfp);
        if(ifp != NULL)
            fclose(ifp);
        if(ofp != NULL)
            fclose(ofp);
    }   
    else{
        printf("Must have both input and output files\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    free(itR);
    free(itI);
    free(itJ);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Can I suggest trying to break this down into smaller pieces and testing them individually? Try to encapsulate your list operations in functions that manipulate the list structure. Even though this is C and not C++, it will pay off to build abstractions and to isolate operations on those abstractions.

Comment: Post the minimum input file that exhibits this behaviour. BTW: `char type[1]` is a problem here. in this buffer of length 1 you can store a string with a maximum length of ... 0. Try `char type[20]`. Also mnemonic can conain strings with a maximal length of only 4.

Comment: The size of my chars worked out just fine for me since the file im reading is going to be for sure in the format i just posted.

Comment: @zombiecircus. You are experiencing a buffer overflow. The `type` buffer cannot hold a string of length one because you don't take info account the zero terminator. Similar problem form for the `mnemonic` buffer. Try  `char type[10], mnemonic[20];` and look if it works better.

Comment: oh ok. so I changed the size of the chars, but the result is still having the same trouble.

Comment: Show the code that calls `linkTypeInstr`.

Comment: Just added the main method that's calling the code

Comment: @zombiecircus you should probably follow sfjac's advice (first comment)

Comment: @MichaelWalz yea im gonna try that, thanks for helping me tho!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is this line:

`temp -> mnemonic = mnemonic;`

The fact that temp->mnemonic is a pointer means that it will allways point to the same 11 chars of the mnemonic array. As head is assigned from temp also head->mnemonic will point to the same 11 chars which will be overwritten at the next call to fscanf.

The solution is to change your

`struct Instr {
        uint32_t uid; /* Unique identification bits */
        uint32_t pretty; /* The type of pretty print format this Instr is */
        char *mnemonic; /* The human readable mnemonic */
        struct Instr *next; /* Pointer for doubly linked list */
        struct Instr *prev; /* Pointer for doubly linked list */
};`

to

`struct Instr {
        uint32_t uid; /* Unique identification bits */
        uint32_t pretty; /* The type of pretty print format this Instr is */
        char mnemonic[11]; /* The human readable mnemonic */
        struct Instr *next; /* Pointer for doubly linked list */
        struct Instr *prev; /* Pointer for doubly linked list */
};`

and instead assign it with strncpy:

`strncpy(temp -> mnemonic, mnemonic, 11);`

Comment: By the way, you should also be aware that fscanf does not return a pointer, instead it returns the number of items successfully matched. Your while loop should check that it returns 4 instead of something else than NULL. A good compiler would warn you about this with a warning message something like: warning: comparison between pointer and integer

Comment: is there a way to fix it without changing the struct itself?

Comment: @zombiecircus Use `strdup` to duplicate the string (or the more portable `malloc` and `strcpy`). Both require you to call `free` after you're finished with the memory, meaning in your `destroy_item` function, or whatever function you use to deallocate memory used by an item, you must call `free` with the mnemonic as the argument before freeing the item to which it belongs.